# display row values as a column name as well as display the details in SQL Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following table as a result of sql query:

```
Course Name  |Date     | PersonName
-------------------------------------
Computer     |01/2015  |John
Computer     |01/2015  |Smith
Soccer       |01/2015  |Julia
Soccer       |01/2015  |Peter
Reading      |03/2015  |Julia
Math         |02/2015  |Peter
```

I would like to display the data at the SQL Server Report as the following :

[image]

I have tried using Matrix by choosing the row groups Course Name  and the column groups Date then the personName under details but under details section I don't need an aggregate (e.g. : Max, count ...) instead it should display the al Personnames as shown in the image and each person has its seperate cell can you please help on this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add grouping by Name in the Value cell.[image: a Picture]